# ROS and real time kernel

Tags: ros, real-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS, but I really need it for my project. I know there has been a few questions about ROS and real time, and I heard that ROS is NOT real time, and I need to use OROCOS if I need real time.

But, I rather not deal with OROCOS at the moment, and I would like to know if there is anyway to use a real time kernel, like rt-kernel or Xenogami, with ROS. I could not find a good instruction on how to do so..Is there any document or tutorials about it?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62862/ros-and-real-time-kernel/) by [sdfzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4904/sdfzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
The vanilla Linux kernel has provided quite decent real-time performance for many years. Unless you have unusually tough latency or hard-response guarantees, it will probably work fine.

**Comment by [sdfzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4904/sdfzz/) on 2013-05-28**:
Thank you for your reply...I will check vanilla kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A non-OROCOS approach for having hard realtime guarantees in the controllers is used on the PR2. You can read some further info on that [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10432/what-real-time-mechanism-of-pr2-use/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdfzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4904/sdfzz/) on 2013-05-28**:
Thank you for your reply.. I guess I will try one of real time kernels...